# Using Scribe library for Oauth in Twitter with callback url

Tags: java, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, scribe

I am implementing twitter in my application using scribe.
After the user authenticate my app and is redirected to new url,
I got the oauth_token and oauth_verifier but could not figure out how to generate oauth_token and oauth_secret from it.
Kindly resolve the issue and thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved the problem just make a new service builder(as in the example) in the redirected page and use the oauth_token and oauth_verifier u'll get when u will be redirected to new page like this

```
Token requestToken = new Token(request.getParameter("oauth_token"),request.getParameter("oauth_verifier"));
Verifier verifier = new Verifier(request.getParameter("oauth_verifier"));
```

rest is same as in example.

Comment: mhh i had the same problem, i tried saving the old request Token and creating it the way you suggested, i even get an access token, but every time i try fetching data through the api i get an error message.

Comment: There is no need to save the old request in case of Twitter(but might be useful in case of LinkedInn).Just use the oauth_token and oauth_verifier you got in the response to create a new requestToken.

Answer (score 2):

[See the Twitter example.](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/TwitterExample.java)

The oauth token and verifier should be what you need to request an access token and access protected resources.

Comment: I have read the example but the example illustrates a PIN based authentication whereas i dont want such in my application.
I am stuck at the point where in example the verifier is used coz i dont have any in case of callback_url.
Kindly help me with another approach.

Comment: what do you mean by PIN based authentication? Do you mean that you do not want the user to have to paste the verifier? I guess a good question is which of the options listed in https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens do you want to use?

Comment: Actually i dont want user to the Verifier PIN and want to redirect it to a new page thats it.